# Ideas on logic for a form that have dynamic elements and need to be saved in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have this form with a select dropdown field.  And with jQuery I am allowing users to add more selection dropdowns via a clone function.  However because of this dynamic context, how do I properly code the logic of saving the form via PHP?

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
     <div class="row">
          <select name="items">
               <option value="box1">Box 1</option>
               <option value="box2">Box 2</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<a href="#" class="add">ADD</a>
```

JS

```
$( 'a.add' ).click( function() {
     var clone = $( 'form .row:first-child' ).clone( true );
     $( clone ).appendTo( 'form' );
} );
```

PHP

```
if ( isset( $_POST ) && $_POST['submit'] === 'submit' ) {
     $items = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['items'] );
     $text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );

     if ( isset( $items ) )
          // do save db routine

     if ( isset( $text ) )
         // do save db routine
}
```

So if you look at the above PHP code, it is for the normal form before any dynamic items have been added and it works fine...But I am just at a lost on how to go about altering this if dynamic elements are added.

Please note that each select and input has to belong together.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You are cloning your element's that mean's you end up having multiple element's with same name..

Comment: exactly - this is why I posted the question asking how to handle this.  I would assume to use an array for the names but not sure if that is the best.

Comment: `$( clone ).prop("name","newName").appendTo('form');` You can set a new name to cloned element

Comment: Yes I understand that however where I am confused is how to handle this in PHP where I can output the form again with the correct values and group together.  Because since this is dynamic, my form output needs to be dynamically pulling the data back out depending on how many saved values there are.

Comment: I believe one way is to use AJAX to submit the data instead because it would be much easier to handle the form elements with jQuery than it is for PHP.  Because with jQuery, I can just loop through the "row" div and build an array for that and then pass it to PHP.

Comment: Even if you add elements with jQuery to the form... ...shouldn't PHP retrieve these elements as well? As long as a ordinary submit is done.

Comment: yes it does and that is not what I am confused about.  I don't know how to group them together properly so I can save and retrieve them as a group.  Because if you look, I can have multiple "row" items each with a select and input field.  But how to keep them separate when saving...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the way I resolved this was to use arrays for the field names so for example from the above code.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
     <div class="row">
          <select name="items[]">
               <option value="box1">Box 1</option>
               <option value="box2">Box 2</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="text[]" value="" />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<a href="#" class="add">ADD</a>
```

So this resolves the duplicate field names when jQuery clones it.  And in PHP, I count how many items were submitted for one of the fields and use that as the bases of looping through the form items like so.

```
// get all data from db here
$count = count( $items );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
 // loop through form items here
}
```